# Connect outlet between table view and viewcontroller with storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, ios6

I'm trying to connect an outlet between a *table view* and the *viewcontroller.h* by using drag and drop. I'm using [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_6_iPhone_Twitter_Integration_Tutorial_using_SLRequest) tutorial. My problem occurs at the following instruction:

- Select the Table View object and display the Assistant Editor using
  View -> Assistant Editor -> Show Assistant Editor menu option.
- Ctrl-click on the Table View object in the view and drag the
  resulting line to the area immediately beneath the @interface directive in the Assistant Editor panel.
- Upon releasing the line,
  the connection panel will appear. Configure the connection as an
  Outlet named *tweetTableView* and click on the Connect button.

I do not get the option to connect the two *(by drag and drop)*. I have done it with a webview before and that all works correctly. The dragging also works for me in the *storyboard* itself but not when i drag to the *viewcontroller.h* file. Maybe its my *storyboard setup*; that is as follows:

Tab bar controller (Start point)

- Navigation controller  ---> Table view controller
- View controller (with webview inside )

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Make sure the assistant editor is set to automatic, and that the right file (viewcontroller.h) is shown.

Comment: If the table view is not owned by the `viewcontroller` you won't be able to connect them.  (Your setup description suggests that the table view has its own controller.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a Tab bar? Then, you must have another viewcontroller (let's say viewSecondViewController.h) associated to the second tab bar..

[image]

In that "ViewSecondViewController.h" you can drag and link...